# Python Renaming tar file contents without extracting

Tags: python, tarfile

I have a TAR file that is created on one machine and is extracted on another machine. Recently I have learned that some coworkers are opening the tar in 7-zip and renaming some of the folders. As an example the created tar *my_tar.tar* has:

```
├── dir1
│   ├── sub-dir1
│   │    ├── file1
│   │    ├── file2
│   ├── sub-dir2
│   │    ├── file3
│   ├── file4
├── dir2
│   ├── file5
├── dir3
│   ├── file6
│   ├── file7
```

Previously they were placing the TAR on a RHEL machine in their home directory */home/user1/my_tar.tar*. then extracting it in that location and moving *sub_dir1*, *sub_dir2*, and *file4* to */dir1*.

To avoid having to do that manual move on the target RHEL machine they started taking the file, opening it in 7-zip, right-clicking on *dir1*, selecting rename, and putting a '/' in front (making it now say */dir1*). Then moving the TAR to their home directory */home/user1/my_tar.tar* and extracting it.

The TAR is created via a python script and I am trying to do that rename process through scripting. Right now I have dir2 and dir3 (with their sub-elements) successfully added to the tar via

```
# tar_file_path is a local path the tar file should be created at
with tarfile.open(tar_file_path, "w", format=tarfile.GNU_FORMAT) as tfh:
    # unmod_path is a Path to the directory containing dir2 and dir3
    for sub_path in unmod_path.iterdir():
        tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=sub_path.name)
```

I have looked at the related questions and hav not found a solution that does not involve extracting files to a different location. I am specifically looking for a means of doing the equivalent of the 7-zip rename as part of building the TAR or after the tar has been created.

I've tried adding the following loop into my with statement above. Each of the commented out lines in the loop represent different forms of the add I have tried.

```
    # mod_path is a Path to the directory containing dir1
    for sub_path in mod_path.iterdir():
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"/{sub_path.name}")  # 1
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"//{sub_path.name}")  # 2
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"\\{sub_path.name}")  # 3
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"/\\{sub_path.name}")  # 4
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"//\\{sub_path.name}")  # 5
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"\\/{sub_path.name}")  # 6
        # tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=f"\\//{sub_path.name}")  # 7
        pass
```

None of them have worked. Some resulted in no change while others resulted in an empty directory in the tar with no name, an empty directory named *dir1*, and both *sub_dir1* and *sub_dir2* at the same level as *dir2* and *dir3*.

I have also tried to create TarInfo objects (using the gettarinfo from tarfile) and adding them to the tar for each individual file (by using the addfile from tarfile) for all files under the dir1 directory (file1, file2, file3, and file4). This most commonly lead to it saying all files were added but extracting the TAR led to errors on the file that was put in the tar with the file appearing to be corrupted when opened with Notepad++.

Comment: TAR files necessarily can only append new information: you can't change the names in tarinfo structures or otherwise "in place". The solution then involves creating two Python tarfile objects: the existing for reading, and a new one hat will be created with the renamed itens, getting the "tarinfo" for each object on the first, modifying it, and adding it to the second, and then replacing the file on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to use the filter parameter of the add method. By having a function that takes the TarInfo and modifies the name to put the "/" in front it works. The code is as follows:

```
# mod_path is a Path to the directory containing dir1
def adjust_name(info: tarfile.TarInfo) -> tarfile.TarInfo:
    info.name = "/" + info.name
    return info

for sub_path in mod_path.iterdir():
    tfh.add(sub_path, arcname=sub_path.name, filter=adjust_name)
```

Comment: that will change the transisent tarinfo information for each file, but will do nothing in the existing tarfile object, of course.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the I was looking to modify the path as I was creating the tarfile so this solution appears to be exactly what I needed to do.